# How do I upload an application on App Store privately?

Tags: ios, upload, app-store

I want to upload an iOS app on the App Store. But I want to be privately. So the public can't see the app if they search for it. But everyone with an link for the app, to see it, and download it. Is it possible on the App Store to do this? If not, are other ways to do this?

I understand that on TestFlight I have to add every tester, and the build expires after 90 days. And I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No App Store not allow this but you can distribute your app privately using Apple's Developer enterprise program for private distribution. these type of apps hosted on your server.
Read more about the enterprise account : https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

you can find a article to using the enterprise account : https://medium.com/apps-studio/distributing-enterprise-ios-app-in-house-without-mdm-3ed015009893

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to upload an IPA file and all the devices added to your account and provision profile would be able to download the app using a url [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com).

If not then you will have to purchase and enterprise development account from Apple where you can privately host your applications.